# How add deeply nested json-formatted dictionary into pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

How would I get dictionary from the second key named 'intervals' into my dataframe from this json file?

```
{
    "system_id": 3212644,
    "total_devices": 1,
    "intervals": [
        {
            "end_at": 1656504900,
            "devices_reporting": 1,
            "wh_del": 0
        },
        {
            "end_at": 1656505800,
            "devices_reporting": 1,
            "wh_del": 0
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "status": "normal",
        "last_report_at": 1656588634,
        "last_energy_at": 1656588600,
        "operational_at": 1655953200
    },
    "meter_intervals": [
        {
            "meter_serial_number": "122147019814EIM1",
            "envoy_serial_number": "122147019814",
            "intervals": [ ## <<-- I want the dictionaries in below here
                {
                    "channel": 1,
                    "wh_del": 0.0,
                    "curr_w": -2,
                    "end_at": 1656504900
                },
                {
                    "channel": 1,
                    "wh_del": 0.0,
                    "curr_w": -3,
                    "end_at": 1656505800
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I've tried the following:

**pd.json_normalize(converted,record_path='intervals')** - But only recognises the first 'intervals' key

**df = pd.json_normalize(data)** - Still groups intervals under "meter_intervals"

So tried referencing **df['meter_intervals']** - this got rid of the first "duplicate key,different depth" issue, but since it is still deeply nested, I wanted to find a more elegant solution. I dont know whether the pandas library can help me here. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
{
    "0": [
        {
            "meter_serial_number": "122147019814EIM1",
            "envoy_serial_number": "122147019814",
            "intervals": [
                {
                    "channel": 1,
                    "wh_del": 0.0,
                    "curr_w": -2,
                    "end_at": 1656504900
                },
                {
                    "channel": 1,
                    "wh_del": 0.0,
                    "curr_w": -3,
                    "end_at": 1656505800
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what about `pd.DataFrame(data['meter_intervals']['intervals'])`? where data is your dictionary

Comment: Ah yes that helps me thanks @Tranbi . I see that meter_intervals is a list and intervals data is a dictionary nested within another list. Therefore I would just need to include the list index:
df2 = data['meter_intervals'][0]['intervals']

Works! thank you!

Comment: Oh right! I missed the list bracket! Glad I could help anyway!